# MLE and binary variables

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, binary-data, discrete-distributions

Suppose $z$ and $y$ are discrete random variables taking values 0 or 1. The distribution of $z$ and $y$ is given by $$P\{z=1\}=\alpha$$ $$P\{y=1|x\}=\frac{e^{\gamma x}}{1+e^{\gamma x}}\\ z=0,1$$

Here $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are scalar parameters of interest. How can we find the MLE and asymptotic distribution of ($\alpha$,$\gamma$) from a random sample

I know the steps to find the MLE such as taking FOCs of loglikelihood for both $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ but I'm facing difficulties understanding how to write the likelihood function.

Any hint/idea is appreciated.

Comment: Is z independent of y and x? Does your sample include (x, y, z) tuples?

Comment: This is the only information given but I'm guessing that they are independent. Consider that the parameters in the conditional and marginal densities do not overlap

Comment: Okay, that helps. Is this a homework problem or textbook question? If so, please tag the question as [tag:self-study].

Comment: It's a textbook question, I'll add the tag